# Pass Integer Array for Number column in database

Tags: java, oracle

**I have query looks like** `SELECT * from TableName WHERE id= ?`

for `id` field I want to pass array of ids which Number field in `Database`,

I have created Number Array type `i` database, when I pass Array to my prepared statement I get following error.

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT * from Tablename WHERE id= ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got schema.app_id

    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.doTranslate(SQLExceptionSubclassTranslator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:80)
    at org.springfra
```

Comment: Show us the relevant Java code.

Comment: you  cannot pass array of int to this sql native query. You should use loop to execute the query a number of times and store the result into a  `Object[][]` Type..

Comment: i don't think that context switches running this query in a loop several times for different ID is a good idea. I think that passing a list and running the statement with IN where clause like this: "elect * from mytable where id in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)" will get you better performance... you can create a method to get the array to csv string (or there is already in come class, I'm not that Java guy tbh)

Comment: I suspect you're very close and just need a small tweak to the query, but it would really be helpful if you included the Java code.to check how you're passing the array.

Comment: I have select query where condition in (), but the input I am passing in the in condition is too large (as oracle only accept less that **1000** values for IN condition), that's where I tried to create Type array table of Number in oracle and passed Integer array using Oracle Array type to this In condition, that doesn't work though.

Comment: Why don't you want to show the Java code? The definition of your Oracle array type would be helpful too.

Comment: That would have been much better as an edit to the question so it could be formatted and readable. But looks like you're doing what I thought; so does my answer help? If not please comment on that saying why not, e.g any errors you still get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a [table collection expression](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#i2065746) in your query:

> The table_collection_expression lets you inform Oracle that the value of *collection_expression* should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations. The *collection_expression* can be a subquery, a column, a function, or a collection constructor. Regardless of its form, it must return a collection value—that is, a value whose type is nested table or varray. This process of extracting the elements of a collection is called collection unnesting.

So you need to convert your passed collection (array) to a table in a subquery within your `in()` clause:

```
SELECT * from TableName WHERE in (SELECT column_value FROM TABLE(?))
```

Or with a join:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM TABLE(?) i
JOIN TableName t
ON t.id = i.column_value
```

Comment: Thanks Alex for the help, I will try and will let you know.